# Dynamically sql query to select top (n) elements

Tags: c#, sql, .net

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK)  ORDER BY LogTime DESC
```

I want to replace find 'TOP 100' string and replace it with 'TOP 200' or any other value.

Can you please let me know how to do it in C#?

Comment: Where is your c# code?

Comment: show more details! are those strings saved in a text file for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are writing query in your c# code you can use:

```
int topCount=1000;

string query= "SELECT TOP ("+i.toString()+") * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY LogTime DESC"
```

But if you want to send parameter to your SP then you can use:

```
Declare @i int=1000;

 SELECT TOP (@i) * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK)  ORDER BY LogTime DESC
```

Comment: This is a more sane approach than the hack that is the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as if you simply want to replace part of the string with another, so like:

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK)  ORDER BY LogTime DESC";
sql = sql.Replace("TOP 100", "TOP 200");
```

If the number is dynamic and you want to replace it with a different one you could use regex:

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK)  ORDER BY LogTime DESC";
string pattern = @"\bTOP\b *(\d+)";
sql = Regex.Replace(sql, pattern, m => "TOP 200");
```

Comment: Thanks! but its not always TOP 100, it might be TOP 500 or anything else. I need to find what is the value TOP 'anything' from string and then replace it with TOP 'anything'

Comment: @PrinceT: then use regex. I've edited my answer. I',m not a regex expert so maybe it is imrpovable. But it seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/kJ9zI7/1

Comment: okay.. fine.. superb!!

Comment: SQL string replacement is a hack. There's no need for it in this case, see for example yashpal's answer -1

Comment: @Andomar: how do you know the source of OP's string? Maybe he cannot change the input. He didn't ask how to parametrize the TOP-clause but to change an existing sql-string.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @topval int=100

SELECT TOP @topval * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY LogTime DESC
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do it in C#?

Comment: @PrinceT you can use sqlparameters. show your c# code

Comment: This syntax is not valid, try it

Answer (score 0):

you want to use string replace function.[string replace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using stored procedures, you can concatenate the limit in the command text in C#:

```
int toplimit = 200;

cmd.CommandText="SELECT TOP " + toplimit.ToString() + " * FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK)  ORDER BY LogTime DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as simple as this

```
    private string GetSql(int maxRecords)
    {
        string statement = "SELECT TOP " + maxRecords + " FROM DSMS_Log.dbo.LoggingDetail WITH(NOLOCK)  ORDER BY LogTime DESC ";

         return statement;
    }
```

you can also modify the parameters and change your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regex for that. Because i think its the best way to get all variations in one statement.

```
string oldString = "Select top 500 from wherever";
string newLimit = "top 20";
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(oldString , "TOP (\\d)+",newLimit , System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

So put in your old string, replace any "TOP x" string with another version given as newLimit in my Example.

Answer (score 0):

For C# solution you will do better using a parameter instead of string manipulation.

simply like this:

```
int count = 200;
var sql = string.Format("SELECT TOP {0} FROM [Rest_Of_Your_Query]", count);
```

if you will use a parameter it will be easier for you to know when to change (in case you want to replace only when the value is 100) and to which value (200, 300 whatever).

For SQL solution take a look at the answer from @Ganesh_Devlekar